# PyAv av.open() specify used codec

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, pcm, pyav

When PyAv is used to open the alsa audio device. How I can specify used codec and not the ffmpeg default one because that is wrong. By default it will use `pcm_s16le` and I need to use `pcm_s32le`. I can record from my device with following ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -acodec pcm_s32le -i dmic_sv alsaout.wav
```

but not with

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i dmic_sv alsaout.wav
```

Which will give me following error:

```
[alsa @ 0x12061c0] cannot set sample format 0x10000 2 (Invalid argument)
dmic_sv: Input/output error
```

How to transfer the working command to PyAv [av.open()](https://pyav.org/docs/stable/api/_globals.html) function? There is `stream_options` but it doesn't seem to work. I tried

```
stream_options = [{'-acodec': 'pcm_s32le'}]
av.open('dmic_sv', format='alsa', mode='r', stream_options=stream_options)
```

And I get the same as above.

```
av.error.OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error: 'dmic_sv'; last error log: [alsa] cannot set sample format 0x10000 2 (Invalid argument)
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own question because I figured it out. I read ffmpeg source code and saw that when using alsa audio device and codec is not specified ffmpeg will default to use signed 16-bit pcm samples. Code [here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/2ff3c466eca66bb8eb32bb41a4ce70fe285e3ea0/libavdevice/alsa.c#L183). By further exploring the source code the codec value comes from [AVFormatContext::audio_codec_id](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.3/structAVFormatContext.html#ab179ade0dbe905ab2867b7001bf618ec) struct field.

Now figuring out that PyAV using Cython to use FFmpeg and by reading PyAV source code of [Container](https://github.com/PyAV-Org/PyAV/blob/1fa8dd6a95336321feca69b66aebefb4f08d7e85/av/container/core.pxd#L15) class I noticed it holds `AVFormatContext` in it's `self.ptr` variable. Then reading `InputContainer` source code and especially before calling [avformat_open_input](https://github.com/PyAV-Org/PyAV/blob/1fa8dd6a95336321feca69b66aebefb4f08d7e85/av/container/core.pyx#L219) function to open the alsa device. Specifying the used audio codec is not supported by PyAV.

I forked the library and ended quickly hacking the [solution](https://github.com/PyAV-Org/PyAV/compare/main...ArestechOy:user_specified_audio_codec) for me. Now the question is would it be possible to add this feature to PyAV to force the codec used for the audio? In this case when the device is using pcm samples and relying ffmpeg to use choose the default one it will always use 16-bit samples and in my case I needed to use 32-bit samples.

Hopefully this helps someone and save them the trouble I went through :) I also posted this same answer for PyAV issue [here](https://github.com/PyAV-Org/PyAV/issues/699).